# error when merging three tables

Tags: c#

i'm having an error " Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "

```
 // Define the ADO.NET objects.
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_lecturer_project";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dsPubs = new DataSet();

        // Try to open database and read information.
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dsPubs, "tbl_lecturer_project");

            // This command is still linked to the data adapter.
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student_project_choice";
            adapter.Fill(dsPubs, "tbl_student_project_choice");

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_team";
            adapter.Fill(dsPubs, "tbl_team");

            DataRelation SCoiceLec = new DataRelation("SCoiceLec",  dsPubs.Tables["tbl_lecturer_project"].Columns["lecturerProjectId"], dsPubs.Tables["student_project_choice"].Columns["choiceProjectId"]);
            DataRelation SChoiceNTeam = new DataRelation("SChoiceNTeam",dsPubs.Tables["student_project_choice"].Columns["choiceGroupId"], dsPubs.Tables["tbl_team"].Columns["teamId"]);
```

please help. i want to retrieve data from all 3 tables.

Comment: have you stepped thru the code ..? or are you coding and just running better known as `Code and Go`..? what line does the error happen..?

Comment: at the DataRelation. if i comment the two last lines there is no error.

Comment: In both of the DataRelation lines, you are referencing table "student_project_choice" but in the code above, you fill "tbl_student_project_choice"; if not a typo, that is likely the source of the error

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems with your code.  Here is one:

```
adapter.Fill(dsPubs, "tbl_lecturer_project");
```

should be

```
adapter.Fill(dsPubs);
```

---

I think what  you want is this:

```
string selectSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tbl_lecturer_project;
                     SELECT * FROM tbl_student_project_choice;
                     SELECT * FROM tbl_team";

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   con.Open();
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con))
   {
      using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
      {
         DataSet dsPubs = new DataSet();

         adapter.Fill(dsPubs);

         // use dataset.
      }
   }
}
```

The three tables will have the names `Table`, `Table1`, and `Table2`

Comment: should i use data relation to relate the three tables.

Comment: @user2142993 - No idea, need more details, sounds like a new question to me.